# After wordpress upgrade I'm getting wp_user not found in pluggable.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I am calling a php script from an app that checks the credentials of a wp user. This worked fine until I upgraded wordpress from 4.3 to 4.4 (and 4.5). It's really time I got this sorted but I can't think why wp-user is no longer available as it is in the include list.

> error:  wp_user not found in pluggable.php

Please see the code below..

```
define( 'SHORTINIT', TRUE );

require_once $abspath . '/wp-load.php';
require_once $abspath . '/wp-includes/user.php';
require_once $abspath . '/wp-includes/pluggable.php';
require_once $abspath . '/wp-includes/formatting.php';   
require_once $abspath . '/wp-includes/capabilities.php';
require_once $abspath . '/wp-includes/kses.php';
require_once $abspath . '/wp-includes/meta.php';
require_once $abspath . '/wp-includes/l10n.php';
require_once $abspath . '/wp-includes/class-wp-error.php';
require_once $abspath . '/wp-includes/general-template.php';
require_once $abspath . '/wp-includes/link-template.php';

$the_authenticate = wp_authenticate_username_password('null',$user_name,$user_password);
if( is_wp_error( $the_authenticate ) ) {
    echo '{"error":"The username was not recognised"}';
}
else
{
    $the_user_authenticate_id = $the_authenticate->ID;
    $the_user = get_user_by('login', $user_name);
    $the_user_id = $the_user->ID;
if ( !$the_user ) 
{  
   //echo "{'error':'The username was not recognised'}";
}
```

I have found the solution is that I now need to include the following..

```
require_once $abspath . '/wp-includes/class-wp-roles.php';
require_once $abspath . '/wp-includes/class-wp-user.php';
require_once $abspath . '/wp-includes/class-wp-role.php';
```

Please can anyone explain why these extra includes are suddenly necessary in wordpress 4.4 and whether my solution makes sense?

Answer (score 2):

Download the updated wordpress version from wordpress.org and replace your current wp-admin and wp-includes folders with updated wordpress folders.

Hope it will work.